# Ways to apply an applicative functor multiple times

Tags: haskell

Hello fellow Haskellers.

Let's say I have an applicative functor (not an instance of monad) I
want to apply multiple times to a pure initial value. For example,

```
λ> Just (1+) <*> (Just (1+) <*> pure 0)
Just 2
```

If I want to generalize this to any number of consecutive
applications, I can do it with a `fold`.

```
applyAppl :: Applicative f => f (a -> a) -> Int -> f a -> f a
applyAppl f n i = foldr (<*>) i $ replicate n f
```

After this definition,

```
λ> applyAppl (Just (1+)) 10 $ pure 0
Just 10
```

I have an awkward suspicion that the generalization could also be
done with one of the higher-order builtin applicative tools such as `sequenceA` or `traverse`. Can it?

(Edited to take into account the first two comments below.)

Comment: Can you give the type of the function you're trying to write?

Comment: What do you mean by "more easily"? Your function is a single line of code; it doesn't really get much easier than that.

Comment: what simplification you want to do? I tried to think of something, but it really ended up to be some sort of folding, and you must call `<*>` to pull the function from applicative out to be a function in hask.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `iterate`:

```
applyAppl :: Applicative f => f (a -> a) -> Int -> f a -> f a
applyAppl f n i = iterate (f <*>) i !! n
```

Loaded into GHCi:

```
ghci> applyAppl (Just (+1)) 10 (pure 0)
Just 10
```

I'm not sure that's necessarily better than your implementation, since I suspect both implementations fuse into something with essentially the same performance profile (though I haven't tested that), but it is different.

I've seen this sort of "`iterate` with `(!!)`" pattern for memoization so I'm pretty sure that, at the very least, it won't have worse performance.

Comment: Already an improvement, but still requires me to supply `(<*>)` explicitly, in this case to `iterate`. Just trying to understand how the applicative machinery could be used to solve this directly.

Comment: @jhu I'm pretty sure that there is nothing builtin that will avoid that. I could be wrong (especially since it is 2:35 a.m. here, hah), but I can't think of anything at the moment. Of the builtin Applicative functions I can think of right now, none of them have the "statefulness" required (in the way that you need): they don't keep track of the intermediate results in any way. So, for example, something like `(sequence (fmap sequence (replicateM 10 (Just (+1))))) 0` will just give you `Just [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the following variation of @David Young's answer:

```
foo :: Applicative f => f (a -> a) -> Int -> a -> f a
foo f n i = fmap (($ i) . iterateN n) f
   where iterateN n f = (!! n) . iterate f
```

giving:

```
> foo (Just (1+)) 10 0
Just 10
>
```

This uses the "applicative machinery" in the form of the Functor instance for applicatives to perform both the functional iteration and the application without explicit use of `<*>`.  I'm not sure what else you'd be hoping for here.